# Key remapping using xmodmap does not work for some gtk applications

Tags: linux, keyboard, gnome, keyboard-layout

I tried to remap some keys using xmodmap. For example,

`xmodmap -e "keycode 118 = Next"`

maps Insert key of my laptop (XPS 13 9360) to PgDn. It works for some applications such as firefox and visual studio code, but does not work for some other applications including gnome-terminal, xfce4-terminal, epiphany, and gedit. I'm running gnome 3.24 / Wayland / Archlinux. I have no idea why some applications don't work properly with xmodmap. Any suggestion?

---

Edit: Ok, I gave up xmodmap. Instead I decided to touch xkb. Editing some entries of two files `pc` and `altwin` under `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/` seems to work well.

Comment: Thanks, I've been looking all over for a solution to this and your edit finally helped me figure out how to solve this for myself. :)